# Cublas and NaN?

Tags: cuda, nan, cublas

How cublas handle NaNs? Do cublas functions always handle NaNs the way whenever the operation has a IEEE 754 defined behavior with NaNs? I am particularly interested in how they handle NaNs in their gemm and batched gemm routines, so far as I tested, the results with NaNs are in line with the standard, however there is no mention about this in cuda documents, so I am a little bit unsure about it, and to handle NaNs correctly is critical to the correctness of my codes.

Comment: What in particular in the handling of NaNs is critical to your code, and why? How do you address this issue when you use BLAS on the host? I do not recall seeing documentation about NaN handling for any of the commonly used BLAS implementations.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA GPUs should adhere to IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic rules.

There should be no non-standard handling of NaN.  This should apply to all libraries that use floating-point arithmetic, and should not vary from function to function.

[This document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html#abstract) has considerable discussion about GPUs usage of IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic.